# Stop systemd from cleaning my /tmp

Tags: systemd, rm, tmp

Before the advent of systemd, my /tmp was cleaned when and only when I rebooted my machine.  I was happy.

Now systemd has changed this decades-old default so that my /tmp is cleaned every 24 hours, it seems.  I am not happy.

How to get the old please-do-not-touch-my-/tmp-except-when-rebooting behavior with systemd?

I've seen related Q&A's here, but the answers are all too complicated for me:

- [How to edit the timer for systemd-tmpfiles-clean? [duplicate]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452811/how-to-edit-the-timer-for-systemd-tmpfiles-clean?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [systemd timer every 15 minutes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126786/systemd-timer-every-15-minutes)

Comment: Which ones are related? Perhaps we can edit one of those answers to make it clearer.

Comment: Even if the answers are too complicated it would be good to [edit] the question an add links to these answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this into /etc/rc.local:

```
# disable the daily cleaning
systemctl disable systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer
# make sure /tmp is cleaned now (might be superfluous, but what the heck?)
systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
```

and enable rc.local:

```
 systemctl start rc-local.service
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this seems to work just nicely.